# MongoDb transaction with SpringBoot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

I am trying to implement transaction on MongoDb using SpringBoot. Below is the code snippet :

1. Config class :

```
@Bean
@Autowired
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${mongo.transactions}'=='enabled'")
@Profile("enableTransactions")
MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory dbFactory) {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}
```

2. Logic :

```
@Transactional
    public String checkTransactions(RequestDto requestDto) throw Exception{
        requestRepository.save(requestDto);
        throw new Exception();
        return "DONE";
    }
```

But this is not working, the record gets persisted in the DB.

However when I use client.session and MongoCollection instead of spring's annotation, everything works as expected.

Any idea where I am missing something??

NOTE : Mongo's version is 4.4 and Spring's version is 2.2.5

Comment: try enabling transaction using `@enabletransactionmanagement` annotation

Comment: that has also been added in the config class @Deadpool

Comment: The tx never sees the exception, hence it assumes everything is ok and commits. Don't catch the exception and swallow it.

Comment: Even on swallowing the exception the transaction is not getting rollbacked. @M.Deinum

Comment: The problem is **that you are swallowing the exception**. You should throw it **and** configure to rollback on `Exception`. The default is to rollback only on `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: Whether I swallow or throw the exception, I am able to read that record from DB while the current record is under transaction!!!

The problem is not with throwing/swallowing the exception.  @M.Deinum

Comment: And did you actually enable transactions else it won't work either, how are you calling this method?

Comment: yes I have added EnableTransactionManagement annotation in the config class and I am calling this method from controller. @M.Deinum

Comment: Please add all relevant informatin (how you are calling this, the config to enable transactions etc.). Do you have multiple transactional resources (database, jms?) or are you only using MongoDB? Also did you enable the profile **and** have set the property? Also why not using `@ConditionalOnProperty`?